# Hide rows of a pickerView when selecting an item from another pickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I've created a `UIPickerView` using an array as my data source, I'd like to hide some items on the fourth component after I've selected an item on the third one. How can I do that?

```
class ViewControllerEspessuras: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var data = [["1.50","1.60","1.67","1.74"],
                ["-10.00 Esf.","-9.00 Esf.","-8.00 Esf.","-7.00 Esf.","-6.00 Esf.","-5.00 Esf.","-4.00 Esf.","-3.00 Esf.","-2.00 Esf.","-1.00 Esf.","Plano","+1.00 Esf.","+2.00 Esf.","+3.00 Esf.","+4.00 Esf.","+5.00 Esf.","+6.00 Esf.","+7.00 Esf.","+8.00 Esf.","+9.00 Esf.","+10.00 Esf."],
                ["1.50","1.60","1.67","1.74"],
                ["-10.00 Esf.","-9.00 Esf.","-8.00 Esf.","-7.00 Esf.","-6.00 Esf.","-5.00 Esf.","-4.00 Esf.","-3.00 Esf.","-2.00 Esf.","-1.00 Esf.","Plano","+1.00 Esf.","+2.00 Esf.","+3.00 Esf.","+4.00 Esf.","+5.00 Esf.","+6.00 Esf.","+7.00 Esf.","+8.00 Esf.","+9.00 Esf.","+10.00 Esf."]]

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return data[component].count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return data[component][row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let picker1 = data[0][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
        let picker2 = data[1][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(1)]
        let picker3 = data[2][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(2)]
        let picker4 = data[3][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(3)]
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to change the picker rows based on another picker's selection?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8924886/2305521)

Comment: @fpg1503 the linked question it is not Swift

Comment: @LeoDabus there was a [discussion on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303339/2305521) a while ago but I understand that even though it's a question about `UIKit` it may [be beneficial to have a new answer in Swift](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303483/2305521). I tried to write a "language agnostic" answer, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should alter `numberOfRowsInComponent` e `titleForRow forComponent` so they take the selection of the third row into account.

After that you can simply call `reloadComponent` on the last component when the third one is changed.

You can get more info in one of the following SO questions:

- [disabling the values in one component of picker based on value selected in other component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4231084/2305521)
- [How to change the picker rows based on another picker's selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8924886/2305521)